# Split a map into submaps Java

Tags: java, list, hashmap, treemap

I have a map with 10 000 keys and it looks like this:

`Map<String, List<Integer>>`. I want to make a list of `Map<String, List<Integer>>` which will contains 50 submaps X 200 elements.

This is the code:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    map.put(String.valueOf(i),new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Random().nextInt(100),new Random().nextInt(200),new Random().nextInt(300)
    ,new Random().nextInt(400))));
}

List<Map<String, List<Integer>>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Map<String,List<Integer>> submap = new TreeMap<>();

List<Map<String, List<Integer>>> sublist = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> stringListEntry : map.entrySet()) {
    submap.put(stringListEntry.getKey(),stringListEntry.getValue());
    if (submap.size() == 200){
        sublist.add(submap);
        list.addAll(sublist);
        sublist.clear();
        submap.clear();
    }
}

System.out.println(list);
```

but the list by the end is empty.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `sublist.add(submap);` -> `submap.clear();` You use the same instance, and then clear it. Add new instances of submap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a **new** sub-Map when the desired size is reached, instead of cleaning the same sub-Map and placing it into the resulting list multiple times.

```
List<NavigableMap<String, List<Integer>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
NavigableMap<String, List<Integer>> submap = new TreeMap<>();
final int limit = 200;
        
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    submap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    if (submap.size() == limit) {
        list.add(submap);
        submap = new TreeMap<>();
    }
}
```

***Sidenote:** it's more beneficial to use* [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) *interface while working with a* `TreeMap` *because it offers many methods* `firtKey()`, `higherKey()`*, etc. that are not defined in the* `Map` *interface.*